# How to align top x- axes Date labels with bottom x-axes?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

[image: Current result]

I plotted a set of data from a .csv file to show (YYYY-mm-dd) format date on the top x-axis and the float time values on the bottom x-axis by using "twiny". However, the resulting plot which should have been exactly the same seem to coincide only at a central x-axis point suffering a periodic trend of deviation both to the left and right. I have been searching extensively to resolve the issue but none of the existing solutions seem to work. The datafile was created using pandas.

I have attached the plotting routine below. Please let me know how I could describe the problem better.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(13,
8),sharex=True,sharey=True)
font = {'family': 'serif', 'serif': ['Times New Roman'],
'color':
'black', 'weight': 'normal', 'size': 17.0}
ax.errorbar(tmid_met_ul, flux_ul, xerr=terr_met_ul,
yerr=flux_err_ul, color='black', fmt='.g', ecolor='gray',
elinewidth=1.5, capsize=3, markersize=13.5, label=None)

ax.set_xlabel('Time in MET (s)', fontsize=20, **tnrfont)


plt.plot(x1_data, y1_data, '_', color='blue', alpha=0.6)
plt.quiver(x1_data, y1_data, 0, -1, color='blue', alpha=0.6,
width=0.00225, headwidth=4.75, headlength=5)
plt.xticks(fontname = "Times New Roman")
plt.yticks(fontname = "Times New Roman")
ax.set_ylabel(r'Flux (ph cm$\mathbf{^{-2}}$
s$\mathbf{^{-1}}$)', fontsize=20, **tnrfont)
ax.xaxis.set_tick_params(labelsize=17)
ax.yaxis.set_tick_params(labelsize=17)

ax2 = ax.twiny()

ax2.scatter(new_df['tmid_date_STR'].tolist(),new_df['flux'],
color = 'red')

ax2.tick_params(rotation=90)
plt.savefig("lightcurve_weekly.pdf", dpi=250, facecolor='w',
edgecolor='w',orientation='landscape', papertype=None,
format=None,transparent=False, bbox_inches='tight',
pad_inches=0.05,frameon=None)
```

Comment: Your dates look to be strings.  Convert to datetime.

Comment: @JodyKlymak I had converted the strings to datetime by using parse_dates and also transforming them to index while importing the data from .csv file but it doesn't resolve the problem. The only difference from the plot provided above to the one resulting from the datetime objects was that the data points suffered a greater offset in the other direction(i.e., the red points which are shifting away(outwards) from the original green points as we approach the left-right edges of the plot from center in the attached figure instead shift towards the center).

Comment: Actually I can get the job done by using a crude solution which "solves" the issue by using ax.set_xlim where I can specify the arguments of ax.set_xlim as (xlim_min-offset, xlim_max+offset). But the offset value is of course guesswork. I was hoping to use something more general.

Comment: Its basically impossible to help if you don't give us some idea what your input data is.  But if you convert both x values to datetime, you should have no problem aligning the axes.

Comment: I tried converting the x(bottom) axes data to datetime following your suggestion but with no luck. I tried to attach my datafile but I can only see options to attach image files or hyperlinks. my y axis values are [7 x 10^-7 units], x(bottom) axis values are [4 x 10^8 units] and the x(top) axis is datetime.

Comment: Just make a self-contained example with fake data that has the same format as your actual data.